# Most 'unintuitive' application of the Axiom of Choice?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, big-list, axiom-of-choice, intuition

It is well-known that the [axiom of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) is equivalent to many other assumptions, such as the [well-ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem), [Tychonoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem), and the fact that every vector space has a basis.  Even though all these formulations are equivalent, I have heard many people say that they 'believe' the axiom of choice, but they don't 'believe' the well-ordering principle.

So, my question is what do you consider to be the most unintuitive application of choice?

Here is the sort of answer that I have in mind.

An infinite number of people are about to play the following game.  In a moment, they will go into a room and each put on a different hat.  On each hat there will be a real number.  Each player will be able to see the real numbers on all the hats (except their own). After all the hats are placed on, the players have to simultaneously shout out what real number they think is on their own hat.  The players win if only a finite number of them guess incorrectly.  Otherwise, they are all executed. They are not allowed to communicate once they enter the room, but beforehand they are allowed to talk and come up with a strategy (with infinite resources).

The *very* unintuitive fact is that the players have a strategy whereby they can *always* win.  Indeed, it is hard to come up with a strategy where at least *one* player is guaranteed to answer correctly, let alone a co-finite set.  **Hint**: the solution uses the axiom of choice.

Comment: I would guess that Banach-Tarski is about as unintuitive a result as there is.

Comment: The Banach-Tarski paradox loses some its counterintuitive appeal once you know how it works, but then the fact that it doesn't work in for disks in the plane becomes a little shocking.

Comment: True, but I could say that any apparently counterintuitive theorem loses either the property of counterintuitiveness or of truth once you know how it either works or doesn't, respectively.

Comment: Not Banach-Tarski, its ramifications never stopped surprising me.

Comment: This blog post is somewhat relevant: http://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2007/09/13/the-axiom-of-choice-is-wrong/.  I especially like Terence Tao's comment.

Comment: The existence of undetermined games is an easy application of the axiom of choice, and somewhat strange. Another is the existence of a set in the plane that intersects every line exactly twice, though it is not known whether choice is needed for that one.

Comment: OK so I am going to call "nonsense" on this one. Correct me if I'm wrong! I think the fallacy (in the O'Connor article cited in Francois' article below) is that one is attempting to do probability, but the first step of the game, namely that someone picks a random function R-->R, is meaningless until someone puts a probability distribution on this space of functions. And when one does this the argument seems to me to break down. Am I wrong? I'm sure someone will let me know if I am!

Comment: So, just to clarify, my objection to the prisoner game above is that in the purported solution one is going to use probability theory to argue that a certain event has probability 1. But it seems to me that this argument implicitly assumes that the random numbers on the hats are "uniformly chosen", which is of course well-known to be impossible. Once you put a probability distribution on the way one assigns the random numbers to the hats the argument seems to me to break down.

Comment: To give an extreme example, let's assume that the hat-numbering guy does not attempt to "choose a function at random" but simply always labels each hat with the number 0. Then it seems to me that precisely the same argument used to justify that the prisoners will win with prob 1 now also proves that they will win with prob 0, because what are the "chances" (whatever that means!) that they'll choose the zero function within its hugely uncountable equivalence class?? Zero! 

Comment: I also have some issues with the O'Connor article, so I would be interested to see how people chime in.  However, as I stated the problem, there really is no probability involved.  When I say that the prisoners can *always* win, I really mean that they can always win, not just with probability 1.  That is, we can allow an adversary to choose the numbers and the prisoners will always triumph.  

Comment: To clarify, what I mean is that as a *group*, the prisoners will always win (only a finite number of them incorrectly).  But, if we now ask the question 'what is the probability that a *particular* prisoner guesses correctly?', then we have to define what we mean by this.  The solution *suggests* that this probability (whatever it is) is high because no matter how the numbers are chosen only a finite number of prisoners guess incorrectly.  However, I suspect that this intuition is actually wrong since we can't put a meaningful probability distribution on the set of outcomes as Kevin says.  

Comment: @Kevin - In the case that the hat-numbering guy labels each hat with 0, it is not necessary that the prisoners output the zero function.  Indeed, *any* representative of the equivalence class of the zero function will do.  You may be thinking that the zero function is the most canonical choice as a representative for its equivalence class, but it really isn't.

Comment: @Tony: aah, this was a misunderstanding on my part. I had assumed that in this multi-player situation, each one was choosing their equivalence class representative independently. Of course in this multiple-player situation they can all decide to choose the same function, so this is fine. OK so my objection is with the O'Connor article, not this problem. The O'Connor article has a different slant: "just one prisoner" as it were.

Comment: An interesting comment I heard from a logician: In both the finite and infinite case, only a finite number of players gets it wrong.

Comment: @gowers is that intersecting every *straight* line exactly twice?

Answer (score 172):

I have enjoyed the other answers very much. But perhaps it
would be desirable to balance the discussion somewhat with
a counterpoint, by mentioning a few of the
counter-intuitive situations that can occur when the axiom
of choice fails. For although mathematicians often point to
what are perceived as strange consequences of AC, many of
the situations that can arise when one drops the axiom are
also quite bizarre.

- There can be a nonempty tree $T$, with no leaves, but which has no infinite
  path. That is, every finite path in the tree can be extended one more step, but there is no
  path that goes forever.
- A real number can be in the closure of a set $X\subset\mathbb{R}$, but
  not the limit of any sequence from $X$.
- A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ can be continuous
  at a point $c$ in the sense that $x_n\to c\Rightarrow f(x_n)\to f(c)$,
  but not in the $\epsilon\ \delta$ sense.
- A set can be infinite, but have no countably infinite subset.
- Thus, it can be incorrect to say that $\aleph_0$ is the smallest infinite
  cardinality, since there can be infinite sets of
  incomparable size with $\aleph_0$. (see [this MO
  answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25132/cardinality-why-is-there-no/25152#25152).)
- There can be an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$, such that the number of equivalence classes is strictly greater than the size of $\mathbb{R}$. (See [François's excellent answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22927/why-worry-about-the-axiom-of-choice/22935#22935).) This is a consequence of AD, and thus relatively consistent with DC and countable AC.
- There can be a field with no algebraic closure.
- The rational field $\mathbb{Q}$ can have different nonisomorphic algebraic closures (due to Läuchli, see Timothy Chow's comment below). Indeed, $\mathbb{Q}$ can have an uncountable algebraic closure, as well as a countable one.
- There can be a vector space with no basis.
- There can be a vector space with bases of different
  cardinalities.
- The reals can be a countable union of countable
  sets.
- Consequently, the theory of Lebesgue measure can fail totally.
- The first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$ can be
  singular.
- More generally, it can be that *every* uncountable $\aleph_\alpha$ is
  singular. Hence, there are no infinite regular uncountable
  well-ordered cardinals.
- See the [Wikipedia
  page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice#Statements_consistent_with_the_negation_of_AC)
  for additional examples ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Axiom_of_choice&oldid=1173520442#Statements_consistent_with_the_negation_of_AC)).

Comment: My personal favorite is the partition of $\mathbb{R}$ described in this MO post - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22927/why-worry-about-the-axiom-of-choice/22935#22935

Comment: Counterpoint is appreciated.

Comment: Just to add on the smallest infinity, $\aleph_0$ is always the only smallest infinity - regardless to the amount of choice. As you said, there might be other incomparable cardinalities. Another extremely bizarre is exercise from Jech's *The Axiom of Choice* - There exists a model such that for every $\alpha$ there is $X_\alpha$ a countable union of countable sets and $P(X_\alpha)$ can be split into $\aleph_\alpha$ many nonempty parts.

Comment: Asaf, I was referring to the distinction between "minimal" and "smallest" in a partial order (without AC the natural order on cardinalities may not be linear). In this terminology, it can be incorrect to say that $\aleph_0$ is the (or even a) smallest infinity, since when there are infinite Dedekind finite sets, then $\aleph_0$ is merely minimal as opposed to smallest among infinite cardinalities. 

Comment: Another example, due to Läuchli, is that $\mathbb Q$ can have non-isomorphic algebraic closures.  Here, an algebraic closure of a field $K$ is defined to be an algebraically closed extension of $K$ that contains no algebraically closed subfield.  In the absence of choice, you can have an algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ that is a countable union of finite sets but is not itself countable.

Comment: Resurrecting an old answer here:  It should be noted that many of these can be ruled out by resorting to countable AC or dependent choice, which avoid many of the strange consequences of full AC.  For example, "A set can be infinite, but have no countably infinite subset", is ruled out by countable AC.

Comment: One of the worst: The discrete topology on $\omega$ is second countable but not Lindelof... :-) (I believe that this is due to Herrlich, it holds in the basic Cohen model with a D-finite set of reals)

Comment: If this is meant as an argument in favor of adopting AC, it's not a very good one. If AC is too strong then ¬AC is weak and consistent with lots of weird models of ZF along with the correct one. ZF can't prove that the moon isn't made of green cheese, so there are models where it is. It doesn't follow that we should adopt the axiom "nothing is made of cheese".

Comment: Where can I read about the leafless tree with no infinite paths?

Comment: @MichaelHardy The existence of such a tree is exactly equivalent to the failure of DC, if you think about what that means. You would have a relation with no terminal nodes, but no infinite branches. So the tree of finite branches through this relation would be a leafless tree with no infinite paths.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins : That's one of a number of things that make me suspect that set theory as we know it will some day be superseded by some way of doing it right instead, which is perhaps not yet imagined today.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Do you mean that set theory is wrong to clarify the difference between having DC and not having it? I would think that clarifying this very subtle distinction is one place where set theory has proved its value. We now completely understand the foundational issues surrounding AC and DC that had vexed previous generations of mathematicians.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the third point can only hold at a point, not everywhere. A function sequentially continuous everywhere is also continuous everywhere in ZF.

Comment: @Ynir Thanks, I have edited.

Comment: The claim that "the theory of Lebesgue measure can fail totally" (in the absence of AC) is not entirely correct.  One can still develop the Lebesgue measure, as [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3721807).  It's just not necessarily sigma-additive.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Sure, one can define other mathematical things. But to my way of thinking, $\sigma$-additivity is an essential feature of the Lebesgue measure, so much so that if one has a measure-like thing that is not $\sigma$-additive, then one doesn't really have the Lebesgue measure, but something else.

Comment: We use a definition of Lebesgue measure in ZF similar to Terry Tao's, which becomes the usual sigma-additive Lebesgue measure if one throws in ACC.  I can't see how this would be  "something else".

Comment: If $\mathbb R$ is a countable union of countable sets in a model of ZF, would you say that it is not the real numbers but something else?

Comment: I would say that you don't have the theory of Lebesgue measure in that context. You might have a function of some kind that fulfills (one of) the standard definitions of Lebesgue measure, but it won't fulfill other standard definitions, which are no longer equivalent in that theory. What you would have is a pale shadow of the Lebesgue measure theory.

Answer (score 38):

I highly recommend reading this paper by Chris Hardin and Al Taylor, [A Peculiar Connection Between the Axiom of Choice and Predicting the Future](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~ted/203S10/References/peculiar.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20110608172620/https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Eted/203S10/References/peculiar.pdf)), as well as this shorter piece by Mike O'Connor [Set Theory and Weather Prediction](https://xorshammer.com/2008/08/23/set-theory-and-weather-prediction/).

Comment: NB. The O'Connor piece covers what Tony was talking about with hats.

Comment: (So do Hardin and Taylor.)

Comment: Thanks Francois, the weather prediction angle is quite interesting.

Comment: Hardin and Taylor have a whole book on the topic: "The Mathematics of Coordinated Inference: A Study of Generalized Hat Problems"

Comment: At least in a comment I will include a [JSTOR link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27642415) and DOI: [10.1080/00029890.2008.11920502](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2008.11920502) for the paper *A Peculiar Connection between the Axiom of Choice and Predicting the Future*. (But I assume that the link to the Internet Archive should be rather stable.)

Answer (score 31):

The fact that there exist non-measurable sets is highly counter-intuitive; the reason we don't find it so is that we've all been conditioned from day 1 to do measure theory very carefully, and define Borel sets, measurable sets, etc, so we all know that non-measurable sets exist because what would be the point of doing it all so carefully otherwise. At high school we were all taught that the probability of an event occurring was "do it a million times, count how often it happened, divide by a million, and now let a million tend to infinity". And no-one thought to ask "what if this process doesn't tend to a limit?". I bet if anyone asked their teacher they'd say "well it always tends to a limit, that's intuitively clear". But am I right in thinking the following: if we take a subset $X$ of [0,1] with inner measure 0 and outer measure 1, and we keep choosing random reals uniformly in [0,1] and asking whether they land in $X$, and keep a careful table of the result, then the number of times we land in $X$ divided by the number of times we tried just oscillates around between 0 and 1 without converging? That is fundamentally counterintuitive and in some sense completely goes against the informal (non-rigorous) training that we all got in probability at high school. [if I've got this right!]

Comment: I believe that you have got it right.  This seems somewhat related to Terrence Tao's comment (via Qiaochu's comment).  

Comment: Suppose you construct a non-measurable set of 01-sequences as follows. Call two sequences equivalent if they differ in finitely many places. Choose a sequence from each equivalence class, and then let your set be the set of all sequences that have even symmetric difference with the chosen representative of its equivalence class. It feels as though a random sequence should have probability 1/2 of belonging to the set. And if you change the definition to "symmetric difference has size congruent to 0 mod 100, it feels as though the probability should be 1/100. I'm confused.

Comment: It feels as though a random sequence should have probability 1/2 of belonging to this set". Yeah but I'm not sure this is right. Think about it like this. Say I have a subset X of [0,1] with the property that [0,1] is the disjoint union of X, {1-x:x in X} and {1/2}. It "feels like" mu(X) should be 1/2. But I *think* it's also just as consistent that X has inner measure 0 and outer measure 1. My guess is that the latter is what's occurring in the situation here.

Comment: Another point I wanted to make was that if your set is chosen using AC, then it's not really clear what it means to choose a random real and ask whether it lands in the set. After all, you haven't said what the set is. So I'm not sure we would get this oscillatory behaviour because I'm not sure it's possible to make mathematical sense of the experiment in the first place. I do like it though ...

Comment: I love the paradoxical sets above, which "feel like" a random real should belong to them with probability 1/2. It may be worth mentioning that they are closely related to the non-measurable set found by Sierpinski (1937), assuming the existence of a non-principal ultrafilter on $\omega$.  A non-principal ultrafilter on $\omega$ is a weaker assumption than AC, and I expect it is also weaker than a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$. Can anybody confirm this?

Comment: The fact that a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega$ is weaker than
a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ has been confirmed by Simon Thomas here:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21031/ultrafilters-vs-well-orderings

Comment: This answer is incorrect. If you formalize the notion of random picking, the result is random reals a la Solovay, and these require all subsets of R to be Lebesgue measurable, precisely because it is impossible for a sequence of random independent 0-1 events to oscillate in the way you describe. This follows from the permutation invariance of independent random events.

Comment: I agree with Ron that the answer is wrong, but I don't agree with his reason.  First, one can adjoin random reals (in the sense of Solovay) to models that satisfy choice, and the resulting models will still satisfy choice.  What one cannot reasonably do is to ask whether such a random real belongs to a set $X$ from the ground model.  If one takes that question literally, the answer is no; ground-model sets have only ground-model members.  Some ground-model sets, Borel sets, have canonical extensions $X'$ to the forcing model, and one can ask (see next comment)

Comment: whether a random real is in $X′$, but that doesn't work for "wild" sets $X$. Second, to say that a random real has some property (like being in X) doesn't require Solovay forcing. (People talked sensibly about properties of random reals before Solovay came along). In particular, Kevin's answer can be interpreted as saying that the set $Z$ of those sequences $z$ of reals for which the proportion among the first $n$ terms in $z$ that are in $X$ has liminf=0 and limsup=1 as $n\to\infty$ has measure 1. But I'm fairly confident that this is not the case; $Z$ is also non-measurable.

Comment: It is traditional to say loosely of the adjoined random real "r" that it is a member of the set of irrational numbers, even though of course it is not a member of the old model's irrational numbers. The whole point of forcing is that it gives you a way to settle every question of the form "does r belong to S" in a way that is correct for random objects. Without doing this, you have not really defined a random object completely. So before Solovay, no one had really defined randomness satisfactorily (although of course Cohen had given the main idea).


Comment: @Ron: The first sentence of your last comment is a special case of what I wrote about canonical extensions of Borel sets.  The canonical extension of the ground model's (Borel) set of irrationals is the forcing model's set of irrationals.  The rest of your comment seems to identify the topic of (the second part of) my comment, "to say that a random real has some property" and "talked sensibly about properties of random reals", with "defined a random object completely".  They are actually quite different.  The former is much easier than the latter.

Comment: Kevin, but with the alternative, wouldn't we all require similarly intense training and conditioning to avoid unintentional uses of AC? I can easily imagine analogous conversations with your teacher...

Comment: @Joel: We'd need training to know when something can or cannot be proved using dependent choice, but I think the main question is what is *intuitive* and not what *requires training*.  Arguably it's more intuitive that we have no right to assume unrestricted choice than it is to have non-measurable sets, even though both alternatives require some training to handle correctly.

Comment: "But am I right in thinking the following: if we take a subset X of [0,1] with inner measure 0 and outer measure 1, and we keep choosing random reals uniformly in [0,1] and asking whether they land in X, and keep a careful table of the result, then the number of times we land in X divided by the number of times we tried just oscillates around between 0 and 1 without converging?" I do not think this would be physically possible, actually. Still an interesting question though.

Answer (score 28):

Maybe this is not the kind of application you have in mind, but a well-ordering of the reals seems highly counterintuitive to me. I would argue that well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ is the essence of many of the other counterintuitive results that have been mentioned.

Comment: Some years ago I also thought that well-ordering the reals is unintuitive, but now I know better: When you speak of the reals, you think of the structure of a complete ordered field. But well-ordering only refers to the size of the set. It's merely that first it's hard to imagine a uncountable well-ordering at all.

Comment: I'm not concerned with the algebraic structure of the reals, only the size of the set. Nor do I have trouble with uncountable well-orderings per se; $\omega_1$ is fairly intuitive. I just find it hard to claim intuition about well-ordering the continuum when the known independence results for ZF are so stacked against it.  How can its well-ordering be intuitive when we can't say
what its ordinal number is? And when it is consistent for the continuum to have *no* well-ordering?

Comment: John, does this mean that you find the continuum hypothesis highly counterintuitive?  And does the Banach-Tarski paradox follow from the well-orderability of the reals?

Comment: Timothy, I'm torn about CH. I'd like it to be true, for the sake of simplicity,
but it seems *too* simple to be true. As for Banach-Tarski, I think it follows
from well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$. One has to choose from subsets of
$\mathbb{S}^2$, but I presume there is a definable bijection between
$\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{S}^2$. 

Comment: I don't claim to have much intuition about what a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ would look like (whatever that means), but the existence (even in the absence of AC) of a whole range of well-orderable uncountable sets makes it fairly believable that there's a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to one of them. Banach–Tarski, on the other hand, offers me no intuition even while I stare at its proof.

Answer (score 21):

There can be graphs all of whose cycles have even length and whose 
chromatic number is greater than two. In fact, let $G$ be the graph 
whose vertices are the real numbers, with $x$ and $y$ adjacent if 
$|x-y|=\sqrt{2}+r$, where $r$ is rational. Then $G$ has only even 
length cycles. Assuming that every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable 
(which is consistent with ZF), then the chromatic number of $G$ is 
uncountable. This is a result of Shelah and Soifer. If we assume the 
Axiom of Choice, then the chromatic number of $G$ is two.

Comment: A graph with zero edges is bipartite but its chromatic number is not 2 :-)
$$ $$
That nitpick aside, it's a neat example, though we must be careful to define "bipartite" as "no odd cycles", not the definition suggested by "bipartite = two parts" which is immediately equivalent to "chromatic number at most 2".


Comment: @Noam, yes I realized this also and have changed the wording.

Comment: I find this result quite intuitive. What intuition is it supposed to violate? “Every nice property of finite graphs must fail for infinite graphs?” Anyway, the wording is misleading: since the question asks for unintuitive consequences of the axiom of choice, the first sentence should read “There is no graph ...”, otherwise it looks like the pathological example is constructed using choice.

Comment: This is a pathological consequence of the *failure* of the axiom of choice. In fact, if the axiom of choice for $2$-element sets is false, then there is a $1$-regular graph which is not $2$-colorable.

Answer (score 17):

The Axiom of Determinacy (AD) fails.

What that means: Partition the set *<sup>ω</sup>ω* into two sets *S* and *T*, and think of this partition as a *game* (*S*, *T*) with two players.  To play, player 1 picks a natural number *a*<sub>0</sub>, then player 2 picks *b*<sub>0</sub> (as a function of *a*<sub>0</sub>), then player 1 picks *a*<sub>1</sub> (as a function of *b*<sub>0</sub>), then player 2 picks *b*<sub>1</sub> (as a function of *a*<sub>0</sub> and *a*<sub>1</sub>), and so on until *a<sub>n</sub>* and *b<sub>n</sub>* are selected for all *n* ∈ *ω*.  Then the sequence *a*<sub>0</sub>, *b*<sub>0</sub>, *a*<sub>1</sub>, *b*<sub>1</sub>, … is either in *S* (in which case player 1 wins), or in *T* (in which case player 2 wins).

The game (*S*, *T*) is *determined* if either player 1 or player 2 has a winning strategy, *i.e.*, if there are functions *f<sub>n</sub>*: *<sup>n</sup>ω* → *ω* where choosing *a<sub>n</sub>* = *f<sub>n</sub>*( *b*<sub>0</sub>, …, *b*<sub>*n*–1</sub> ) guaranteed player 1 victory, or similarly for player 2. (We can't have both.)  AD is just the statement that every such game is determined, which is false in ZFC.  As with most of the weird examples, the undetermined game is constructed with a well-ordering of **R**.

What makes this so unintuitive to me is that both AC and AD are generalizations of statements that are easily seen for finite objects.  (Any finite game, or even any game with finite depth, is determined, by an easy induction on the depth.)

There are apparently many set theorists that agree with this assessment, since they try to rescue AD as relativized to *L*(**R**).  That the relative consistency strength of this statement is equivalent to that of large cardinals is considered good evidence that those large cardinals are, in fact, consistent.  More precisely, ZF + AD is consistent iff ZFC + "there are infinitely many Woodin cardinals" is consistent, and AD<sup>*L*(**R**)</sup> is outright provable in ZFC + "there is a measurable cardinal which is greater than infinitely many Woodin cardinals".

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the notation `${}^n\omega$`. What does it mean?

Comment: Just the set _n_-tuples in _&omega;_.  It's usually written as _&omega;<sup>n</sup>_, but that notation could also refer to ordinal exponentiation, which is not quite the same.

Comment: We want to have the cake and eat it too :D.

Comment: @Tran: No problem, just apply the Banach-Tarski theorem to your cake.

Comment: Chad, to support your case for the naturality of AD a bit more: AD is precisely the statement $\neg\forall x_0\exists x_1\forall x_2\exists x_3\cdots A(\vec x)\iff \exists x_0\forall x_1\exists x_2\forall x_3\cdots \neg A(\vec x)$, an infinitary deMorgan law. The truth of the finitary deMorgan law constitutes a proof of determinacy for finite games. 

Comment: You don't need any sophisticated set theory to have examples in which finite and infinite games differ a lot. Compare the prisoners dilemma with the infinitely repeated prisoners dilemma.

Answer (score 15):

The most destructive aspect of uncountable choice is that it conflicts with random choice. With uncountable choice, any object which is constructed using randomness, like a random walk, a random field, or even a randomly picked real number, cannot exist, because there are sets which it cannot consistently be assigned membership to.

In order to define what it means to have a random walk, or a random graph, or a random infinite Ising model configuration, or whatever,  you need to define what it means to have an infinite sequence of random coin flips. The result can be encoded as a real number, the binary digits of which are the results of the coin flip, and if this real number really exists, as an actual mathematical object, then this object either belongs to any given set S, or it doesn't.

It is so intuitive to think of random objects this way, that they are often illustrated with pictures, showing us what they look like (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process for a picture of a "realization" of a random walk). These pictures do not signify anything when the axiom of choice is present.

The reason is that once you have actual random objects, for which you can assign membership to any set S, then you can define the probability of landing in S by choosing random objects again and again, and asking what fraction of the time you land in S. This always converges, because given any long finite sequence of 1's and 0's which represent independent random events, any permutation of the 1's and 0's has the same likelihood. This means that it is probability 0 that the sequence will oscillate in any way, and with certainty it will converge to a unique answer.

This answer is the measure of the set S, and every set is measurable in this universe. This makes analysis much easier, because everything is integrable, measurable, etc. This is so intuitive, that if you look at any probability paper, they will illustrate with random objects without hesitation, implicitly denying choice.

(I realize that this answer overlaps with a previous one, but it corrects a serious central mistake in the former.)

Comment: Ron, I don't understand how you conclude that "this means that it is probability 0 that the sequence will oscillate in any way." Could you expand on this?

Comment: If you have a sequence of independent 0-1 events which are in every way identical, then any permutation of the 0s and 1s is just as likely to occur as any other. In order for the limit not to exist, there must be long segregated 0's followed by segregated 1's. But any segregated sequence of length N is segregated in only a negligible fraction of all permutations of this sequence, and the 0s and 1s can come in any permutation. There is no way in the world that an independent sequence of identical probabilistic 0-1's can fail to converge.

Comment: François, I think Ron is saying that classically, if $S$ is a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$ and $X$ is a random variable that is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, then we can't sensibly speak of "the event $X \in S$"; $a fortiori$, any attempt to formulate a strong law of large numbers for $S$ (by taking, as Kevin Buzzard suggested, a sequence $(X_n)$ of i.i.d. random variables, noting when "the event $X_n \in S$ happens", and seeing what almost surely happens to the proportion of successes as $n\to\infty$) fails. But...

Comment: ...if we discard the axiom of choice in favor of "all sets are Lebesgue measurable," then this sort of reasoning becomes legitimate for arbitrary sets $S$.  Attempts to construct a counterexample by finding "bad" sequences of successes and failures whose proportion of successes oscillates wildly won't work, because such bad sequences will occur with probability 0.

Comment: @Chow-- Thank you for stating it so clearly. I wanted to also emphasize that this is really the only counterintuitive aspect of uncountable choice, all the other examples are special cases. For example, the "predict the future/hats" business is counterintuitive because our intuition suggests that we can choose an infinite sequence of future-events/hat-colors at random. The axiom of choice forbids us from choosing at random. We must choose in an L-like model where choice holds. Similarly, random picks forbid Hamel bases for R over Q and for well-ordering of R, so this is the serious conflict.

Answer (score 13):

One counterintuitive aspect of the axiom of choice is a theorem of Diaconescu and independently Goodman and Myhill that, in some constructive set theories that don't begin with the law of the excluded middle, the axiom of choice implies the law of the excluded middle.  But in other systems such as Martin-Löf type theory, the corresponding form of the axiom of choice is completely constructive and does not imply the law of the excluded middle.

Answer (score 7):

Lebesgue measure exists for every Borel set, and is countably additive.

I've always found it more surprising that our fuzzy intuitive ideas of area and volume can be pushed as far as they can than that they break when you push even further.

Comment: You actually don't need the axiom of choice at all to define the "Lebesgue" measure of an arbitrary sublocale of $\mathbb{R}$ and I found it equaly impressive.

Answer (score 5):

Using AC you can construct a (non-continuous) function that intersects any continuous function on any open interval (or even on any set with positive measure).

Comment: Are you sure choice is needed here? If we partition $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathfrak{c}$ dense sets (for example $\mathbb{R} / $\mathbb{Q}$$), we can intersect 1 continuous function on each one (there are $\mathfrak{c}$ continuous functions). I don't think any part of this requires choice.

Answer (score 5):

Every Vector Space has a Hamel basis. This is something that follows from the Axiom of Choice (though it is usually proved by Zorn's Lemma, which is equivalent to the AC). From this follows that $(\mathbb{C},+)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R},+)$, by considering $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ as $\mathbb{Q}$-Vectorspaces. I found this quite unintuitive.

Comment: This doesn't strike me as any more counter-intuitive than the fact that [0, 1) and (0,1) have the same cardinality...

Comment: @SimonRose I certainly think it's *much* more counterintuitive than *that*. A very simple and explicit bijection $f: (0, 1] \to (0, 1)$ is given by $f(x) = x/2$ if $x = 1/2^n$, else $f(x) = x$.

Answer (score 5):

Since this question has been resurrected...

One of my favorite things about the hat-guessing problem in the question is what happens when you think about it probabilistically.  Let's say the hats are labeled by an adversary, whose goal is to make the players lose.  Let's also say the number of players is countable, which should only make the game easier to win.  A natural strategy for the adversary would be to choose the numbers randomly: say the $i$th hat is labeled with a random value $X_i$, where the $X_i$ are independently chosen from some continuous probability distribution.  Let $Y_i$ be the $i$th player's guess.  $Y_i$ can depend on all the $X_j$, $j \ne i$, but not on $X_i$, so clearly $Y_i$ is independent of $X_i$.  Thus for each $i$, $P(Y_i = X_i) = 0$ since $X_i$ has a continuous distribution.  So each player guesses correctly with probability 0.  By countable additivity, almost surely, no player guesses correctly.  So this is a "proof" that there can't be a strategy that guarantees that even one player guesses correctly.

Can you spot the flaw?

Rot13: Hfvat gur nkvbz bs pubvpr fgengrtl, gur qrcraqrapr bs gur Lf ba gur Kf
vf abg zrnfhenoyr, fb va snpg gur Lf ner abg enaqbz inevnoyrf naq
bar pnaabg qb cebonovyvgl jvgu gurz.

Comment: Rather than say "flaw", as if the proof is inherently wrong, you can ask "can you spot where choice ruins this probablistic argument?". Proofs like these are perfectly OK in a Solovay universe, and probability working correctly can be argued to be vastly more important than ineffable Hamel bases/well-orderings.

Comment: In the hat-guessing game, $Y_i$ need only depend on the $X_j,j\gt i$, which is even less intuitive (a little bit less, anyway) than letting it depend on $X_j,j\ne i$. As stated in a long-ago *Monthly* problem, there is a function $f:s^\omega\to S$ such that, for each sequence $x_0,x_1,\dots\in S^\omega$, one has $x_n=f(x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\dots)$ for all but finitely many $n$.

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer but I think that AC itself is itself not intuitive if we look at it closely enough. The reason we think that AC is intuitive is because we have its counterpart for a finite collection, and we assume that an infinite collection should behave in the same way a finite collection does. That later assumption seems to require some faith, if we don't want to say entirely baseless.

Answer (score 4):

I think that it might not be the *most* unintuitive but the fact there exists sets which intersect with *every* perfect subset (but contains none of them!) of the reals is fairly bizarre.

Answer (score 4):

I know a (perhaps even more counter-intuitive) "game" similar to the one presented in the question. There are 100 people and a room with countable many boxes (numbered by naturals). There is a real number in each box. These 100 people can prepare a strategy and then they are separately going to the room. When one comes to the room he begins to open some boxes. He is allowed to (for example) open infinite number of boxes, then decide which box will be opened next. But on the end there have to remain exactly one closed box. The visitor makes a tip, what number there is in it, and go away. He, of course, can't hint to others. Then all boxes are closed and another visitor comes.

There exists a strategy such that 99 of them gives the right answer.

Hint: The core idea is the same as the one in the problem presented in the question but there is one more step ;-)

Comment: Can you describe the strategy?

Comment: In a nutshell, each person get assigned an infinite sequence of boxes from which he chooses from. Then he first opens the boxes of other players, and see since which index all of their sequences align with a representative sequence (assigned to each sequence separately). Finally, he will make a guess in his sequence further than this index (again, according to a representative).

Answer (score 3):

To me, the only "unintuitive" applications of uncountable choice is when it turns up in physics. The only case I know where this happens is in the maximal-extension theorem of Choquet-Bruhat (QM does not use uncountable choice). This uses local extension properties of solutions to General Relativity to prove, using Zorn's lemma, that there exists a maximal extension. The use of axiom of choice is, I think, essential. I couldn't see how to sidestep it when I read the paper a long time ago (somebody please correct me if I am wrong).

What is the axiom of choice doing in physics?

I believe that it is entirely due to the issue of double-sided maximally extended black holes. A maximal extension of General Relativity can contain "wormhole" like solutions (for example, a charged black holes with two patches connected by an interior region), and there can be countably many such bridges in any asymptotically flat patch. But each of these branches can connect you to another different asymptotically flat region, which might have its own countably infinite collection of bridges to other flat regions. The resulting spacetime is like a tree with countably many branches at each node, where each node represents an asymptotically flat spacetime, and each edge is a double-sided maximally extended black hole bridging the two nodes.

Such a tree can have infinite depth, and you must extend the solution to the whole tree. It seems intuitive that to patch the solutions together you need to extend the local solutions over continuum many nodes, and since GR is hyperbolic, you will get to make some arbitrary choices at each extension step. The dependence on choice then simply shows how unreasonable the maximally extended model of General Relativity is for physics.

Comment: Since this got downvoted, I started to worry that it might be incorrect. In particular, if one considers only regions which are a bounded geodesic distance from a given point, can the tree have infinitely many branchings? But it can, because the scale invariance allows ever smaller maximally extended black holes along a finite length geodesic to accumulate with nothing going wrong at the accumulation point.

Comment: Perhaps this should be a question: is the maximal extension of Chonquet Bruhat always separable? The answer I give says no, but I am doubting now.

Comment: The use of Zorn's lemma is not so shocking once you realise that causal inclusion gives a partial order on the set of all past sets.  BTW, you seem to be talking about two different notions of maximal extensions here. The existence theorem of Choquet-Bruhat discusses maximally _Globally Hyperbolic_ extensions, whereas your examples about black holes are talking about _Analytic_ extensions. They are quite different beasts. 

Comment: @WillyWong: They are not different--- the black holes are not analytic extensions, this is just a mischaracterization, they are globally hyperbolic extensions when you have a collapse, and there is no analyticity required (although people say so a lot for no good reason).