# Bounded sequences with divergent Cesàro mean

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

It is well known that there are bounded sequences with divergent Cesàro mean, i.e., a bounded $a_n$ for which given $$c_N :=  \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n,$$ the sequence $(c_N)_{N\geq1}$ has no limit. A simple example is $a_n = (-1)^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}$, for which the $(2^{n+1}-1)$-th term of the sequence of means is $-1/3$ for odd $n$, and the $(2^{n+1}-2)$-th is $1/3$ for even $n$.

But I don't know of any example which is substantially different.

My question is, then, can the Cesàro mean of a bounded sequence diverge in some other way or this slow but stubborn oscillation is essentially the only example?

---

EDIT:
Is there a simple characterization of the bounded sequences for which the Cesàro means converges?

Comment: $a_n=\{\log\log n\}$ is substantially different (here $\{\cdot\}$ means the fractional part). With this sequence of $a_n$'s, $c_N$ is very close to $a_N$ (unless $a_N$ happens to be *very* close to 0).



Comment: Hmm, I don't have the exact description at hand - but if I recall it right then Cesaro-summation can be seen as matrix-multiplication of a vector *A* (containing the terms of the sequence) and a lower triangular matrix *C* containing the coefficients for "implementing" the Cesaro-summation such that $\small C \cdot A = S $ and *S* contains a sequence approaching the convergent. Then it seems simple to invent any non-converging vector *S* (say, having periodic entries) and premultiply with the inverse of *C*: $\small C^{-1} \cdot S = B $ which produces then in *B* an interesting(?) sequence. 

Comment: A huge amount of information is to be found in G.H.Hardy's last book *Divergent Series* published in 1948 (which I haven't got, unfortunately). This old-fashioned book, by one of the last surviving champions of "hard analysis", is unfortunately not very well-known nowadays, probably because "soft analysis", e.g. functional analysis was much more fashionable then - but renewed versions of "hard analysis" are making comebacks!

Comment: There are many *Tauberian theorems* which say that if the Cesaro means (or other means) converge *and* the sequence $(a_n)$ satisfies an extra condition (called a *Tauberian condition*) then the sequence itself converges (necessarily to the same limit). Famous Tauberian conditions include Littlewood's $na_n > -K$ condition, and stuff about *slowly oscillating* sequences, and many, many other conditions also; as well as stuff used to prove the Prime Number Theorem. As well as Hardy's book, I recommend *Tauberian theory, a century of developments*, by Jacob Korevaar.

Comment: @Zen: "by one of the last surviving champions" - is this a new definition of "surviving", or do you know something necromantic I don't? Also, not sure I agree with your version of history...

Comment: @Zen: (Yes, I know you meant "at the time, one of the last surviving...")

Comment: Let's say that $\sin(\log\log n)$ is a (somewhat) naturally occurring sequence for which the Cesaro means fail to converge. 


Comment: @Yemon: yes, of course, you are right, and you knew what I meant...! Probably my mathematical history is wrong, but I think mathematical style has changed a lot since Hardy (his Course of Pure Math. is from 1905 I think, and Inequalities from 1933), and it doesn't seem likely that his favourite style of mathematics will come back into fashion any time soon. Whether this is a good or bad thing is a very different issue, but certainly others (I can't remember who) have commented that Divergent Series was largely overlooked and ignored until recently maybe, and this is definitely sad if true.

Comment: ...@Yemon: off-topic, sorry, but: I expect Hardy would have absolutely hated Category Theory and many other currently popular things. But we'd better not go there! [I'm sure he would also have hated computers and the internet; you know he didn't use telephones, or even fountain pens?!]

Comment: @Anthony: your examples are cool, but I don't think they're substantially different: they both are oscillating sequences whose speed of oscillation decreases (super-)exponentially. I'm at a loss proving that $a_N \approx c_N$ in your first example; could you point me the way?

Comment: @Gottfried: That's true, but I don't see how to restrict $S$ in order to $B$ be a bounded sequence. For example, if $s_n = (-1)^n$, then $b_n = (-1)^n (2n-1)$.

Comment: @Zen: Thanks for the reference. My university's library does not have the book, I'll try to obtain it via other means. Tauberian theorems are certainly interesting, but they're not what I had in my mind. I'm thinking about sequences that could be interpreted as outcomes of a physical experiment. The Cesáro means need to converge if I want to ascribe an expected value to the measurement (or a probability to a certain outcome). I wanted to find another example to see if there's a reasonable physical experiment that does not have a mean, as I don't find my example reasonable.

Comment: @Mateus: that sounds similar to some comments made about the Axiom of Choice I saw recently:

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20882/most-unintuitive-application-of-the-axiom-of-choice

One answer given there considers repeating an experiment where the set of interest (success) is non-measurable, so maybe the long-run proportion of successful experiments doesn't converge to any limit, so the intuitive idea of probability doesn't make sense. Of course, this is definitely not a "reasonable" physical experiment!

But if Cesaro means don't work, you can always use stronger summation methods.

Comment: @Zen: So my experimentalist complains to me that he can't determine the polarization of a new laser of his, because it's oscillating between horizontal and vertical. He's distressed because he can't even calculate the probability of a given photon having horizontal or vertical polarization, as the probability is also oscillating with time. So I answer him: never fear, you can ascribe a well-defined probability to this event, you only need to use a less naïve means of averaging your results. ;p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choose any bounded infinite sequence $\{ b_m \}_{m \geq 0}$ of integers that is not eventually stationary, and let $a_n = b_{\lfloor \log (\log (n+2)) \rfloor}$.  When $m$ is a large integer, and $N+2$ is almost $e^{e^m}$, the Cesàro mean $c_N$ will be very close to $b_{m-1}$.

If you want arbitrary iterated Cesàro means to diverge, you can replace the double log with a slower-growing function, like the inverse Ackerman function $\alpha$.

Regarding your question, it is not hard to show that if your sequence is bounded, that the Cesàro means $c_N$ can't move very quickly for large $N$.  In other words, you can avoid oscillation in the literal sense, but whatever you have will be slow.

Comment: That's an excellent answer, thanks! But it seems that my question was not very good, I'll edit it a bit. If you can answer the new version, I'd be glad.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know of any simple characterization of bounded sequences that have convergent Cesàro means.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a construction: Choose  real numbers a < c < d < b. Construct a sequence 
**a, b, a, a, ..., a, b, b, ..., b, a, a, ..., a, b, b, ..., b, a, ......**
consisting of blocks of a's and b's as follows: Start with the first two terms a, b. For the first block of a's put enough terms equal to a so that the Cesaro average so far is less that c. Then start inserting terms equal to b, enough of them so that the average so far exceeds d. Then start inserting terms equal to a until the average is less than c, and continue with inserting terms equal to b until the average exceeds d, and so on.